# exec gather table stats from procedure

Tags: oracle

If I create a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SchameB.PRC_GATHER_STATS IS
BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS( 'SchName', 'TableName', CASCADE => TRUE);
END;
```

and execute it ;

```
EXEC SchameB.PRC_GATHER_STATS;
```

this gives me error `ORA-20000: Unable to analyze TABLE "SchameA"."TableName", insufficient privileges or does not exist`. But this works:

```
EXEC SYS.DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS( 'SchameA', 'TableName', CASCADE => TRUE);
```

The user who `EXEC`s the procedure and the table are in different schemas.

Why am I getting an error when doing this through a procedure?

Comment: Not entirely sure I follow; but are you relying on privileges granted through roles, which [won't apply in your procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authorization.htm#autoId16)?

Comment: i understand so how can i apply it to procedure ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To gather statistics on an object in another schema you need the `ANALYZE ANY` system privilege. I appears that the user that runs your procedure has that privilege, but granted through a role. As [the documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authorization.htm#autoId16):

> All roles are disabled in any named PL/SQL block (stored procedure,
>   function, or trigger) that executes with definer's rights.

You can either `GRANT ANALYZE ANY` directly to your user, or create the procedure [with invoker's rights](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809), as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SchameB.PRC_GATHER_STATS
AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS
BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('SchName', 'TableName', CASCADE => TRUE);
END;
/
```

When you `EXEC` the `DBMS_STATS` procedure directly, it's running as an anonymous block, and those always run with invoker's rights - honouring roles.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the procedure to be able to be ran by a user without the `ANALYSE ANY` role then you can set the `AUTHID` to be `DEFINER`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SchameB.PRC_GATHER_STATS
AUTHID DEFINER IS
BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('SchName', 'TableName', CASCADE => TRUE);
END;
```